# SwiftUI: Toggling a JSON property in a List

Tags: swiftui

I have a local JSON file I am importing and decoding.  I am them iterating through that data to create a list.  I have a `Button` and I want to toggle the value of the `favorite` property when the button is tapped.  I realize that would be mutating a JSON value which wouldnt work so I am trying to figure out how to accomplish this.

**Towns.json**

```
[
    {
      "display_name": "California",
      "favorite": false,
    },
    {
      "display_name": "Colorado",
      "favorite": false,
    }

]
```

**Town.swift**

```
struct Town: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {image}
    let display_name: String
    let favorite: Bool
}
```

**MainView.swift**

```
ForEach(towns) { town in
    LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
        HStack {
            Text(town.display_name)
            Spacer()
            Button {
                town.favorite.toggle()
            } label: {
                if town.favorite {
                    Image(systemName: "flame").foregroundColor(.red)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "flame.fill").foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a way to access the original element from the array. In SwiftUI 3 (just announced), this has become much easier, but until that's out, generally people use `indices` or `enumerated` to get an index of the original item (there's also a `.indexed()` from Swift Collections, but it requires importing an SPM package to use it):

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var towns : [Town] = []
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(towns.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,town) in
            LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                HStack {
                    Text(town.display_name)
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        towns[index].favorite.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        if town.favorite {
                            Image(systemName: "flame").foregroundColor(.red)
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "flame.fill").foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also need to change `let favorite` to `var favorite` in your model, since now it's a mutable property.

Comment: thanks, worked great!  I looked up Swift updates announced at WWDC but couldn't find what you were referencing.  Is there somewhere I can read about the addition you mentioned in Swift 3?

Comment: In SwiftUI 3 (not Swift 3), you can just do `ForEach($towns) { $town in }` and modify the `town` directly. It is probably in the "What's New In SwiftUI 2021" session.

Comment: @mitchellOcavoos here's the [session video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10018/?time=422) (starts at 7:02)